# URL validation detect movie title

Tags: php, regex

how can me detect movie title from url..

```
http://www.mysite.com/2430-Moonrise-Kingdom.aspx
http://www.mysite.com/2405-Dark-Shadows.aspx
http://www.mysite.com/2415-Madagascar-3-Europes-Most-Wanted.aspx
```

I need to convert utl from:

```
http://www.mysite.com/2405-Dark-Shadows.aspx
```

to: "*Dark Shadows*" or "*Dark-Shadows*"

**my code is:**

```
$regexUrl = "/\/[0-9]{2,4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.aspx\/?";

echo preg_match($regexUrl, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: Your code is a bit... optimistic. Who sets `$movie_title` and how?

Comment: sorry I gonna fix it, wait...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/2415-Madagascar-3-Europes-Most-Wanted.aspx';

$url = basename($url, '.aspx');
$url = substr($url, 1+strpos($url, '-'));
$url = strtr($url, '-', ' ');

echo $url;
```

But if this is your site you should rather use this:

```
$id = (int)basename($url);
```

and load the title from DB. So even when your URL gets corrupted you can still load proper page.

Comment: I shortened the code by one line, first: parse_url(...) is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to go wrong with your pattern at the end. Try this (note the last few characters):

```
/\/[0-9]{2,4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.aspx/
```

You'll also want to add a group in order to more easily grab the part that is the title.

```
/\/[0-9]{2,4}\-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.aspx\/?
```

Finally, here's a simplified version that won't break if the number at the beginning has one or more than four digits, or if the title has strange characters (perhaps it's not an English-language film).

```
\/\d+-(.+)\.aspx$/
```